# React Native: HOC Missing state when using `onLayout`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This component renders the `Placeholder` & once it gets layout, this HOC updates the state and calls the child with the values.

All good so far, but when the child resizes (`WillChangeSizeIn3Seconds`), render is called again, but this time the state is `{}`.

When it calls `render` the second time, it is actually right before the `componentWillUnmount` call.

Why does the state not persist across re-renders?

```
// HOC

const onLayout = Placeholder =>
    class OnLayout extends Component {
        state = {}

        componentWillUnmount() {
            debugger
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            debugger
        }

        onLayout = ({ nativeEvent: { layout } }) => {
            this.setState({ layout })
        }

        render() {
            const { children, ...rest } = this.props
            const { layout } = this.state

            return layout ? (
                children(layout)
            ) : (
                <Placeholder {...rest} onLayout={this.onLayout} />
            )
        }
    }

// Usage

class TestComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        const OnLayout = onLayout(Loading)

        return (
            <View>
                <OnLayout>
                    ({(width, height)}) =>{' '}
                    <WillChangeSizeIn3Seconds width={width} height={height} />
                </OnLayout>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Where exactly is `const OnLayout = onLayout(Loading)` defined?

Comment: It is defined in another component...

Comment: In case it is defined inside a `render` method, move it to the top level of the module, as that may explain the loss of state on rerender.

Comment: Wow, that was it—thank you so much! Want to answer the question, so I can mark it as the excepted answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the HOC application is inside a render method, which means `OnLayout` will be a different class on each rerender of `TestComponent`. This in turn causes the previous `OnLayout` to be unmounted and replaced by a new one, losing all state.

Some more information can be found in the React docs on HOCs: [Don’t Use HOCs Inside the render Method](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#dont-use-hocs-inside-the-render-method)